# Can we print the data just by using bare address in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I was wondering whether we can print data at a particular location just by using the bare address of that location in C language.

for eg, Here is the code I used :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int num = 10;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &num;

    //To output the address of the "num" variable
    printf("Address: %p\n", ptr);

    //Address is 0x7fff47808f50...

    //Using that address to print the data at variable "num"
    printf("Data: %d\n", *(0x7fff47808f50));

    return 0;
}
```

But it is showing error. Maybe I've used the wrong syntax or maybe this is not the way to do it.Anyhow, please tell me the right way to do it.

Comment: What makes you think there will always be something at adress `0x7fff47808f50`?

Comment: the address changes, it's not always that.. and you'd have to set it into a pointer on integer, otherwise how to decode the type?

Comment: Note that this is the address of variable "num" and I've assigned it the value 10.

Comment: try `int  *p=(int *)some valid address`

Comment: To answer your question. NO. you will need some kind of type or at least a size to print anything from just an adress. You can't just print the data from a random adress

Comment: on some old systems (ex; AmigaOS), it made sense to read data at some physically fixed locations. But not anymore on Linux/Windows boxes, so the question would have to be narrowed down: why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre just for learning purpose, that's it.

Comment: and you're right, address is changing everytime i'm recompiling the code. Why is that ?

Comment: depends on the system memory/state and what memory allocation returns. just don't do that. unless you're using a microcontroller with fixed addresses to read from (which doesn't seem to be the case)

Comment: @YatendraRathore because the operating system chooses the address

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre common in embedded projects. (Maybe not printf but). Not possible to dereference registers without it :)

Comment: Now, even if it does run, do not expect it to give out the data of any location you hard code. You might run into a segmentation fault.

Comment: @PeterJ agreed, but clearly not the meaning of the question of the OP

Answer (score 2):

You *could* (thought shouldn't) cast the integer to a pointer like so: `(void *) 0x7fff47808f50`.

The conversion has implementation-defined and undefined aspects, however, meaning your mileage will vary. The value will obviously change from compiler to compiler, perhaps even for different compilations, and byte order probably won't be the same as the way we conventionally write numbers, meaning you'll probably have to tinker quite a bit to get this working.

This is nonetheless demonstrable in practice, when that implementation-defined behaviour allows us to reproduce that behaviour, the following will be compliant:

```
unsigned long long ptr_as_integer = (unsigned long long) "hello world";
printf("%s", (void *) ptr_as_integer);

int value = 42;
unsigned long long value_ptr_as_integer = (unsigned long long) &value;
printf("%d", * (int *) value_ptr_as_integer);
```

There's also the `uintptr_t` type, which is designed specifically for this, but that's *optional* and so not guaranteed to exist...

It's fine to be curious; that's how we learn best... but please don't use this in practice! How often have you been taught not to use magic numbers?

Comment: Detail: Although certainly reasonable, `(unsigned long long) "hello world";` is not specified to "work" either as `unsigned long long` may lack sufficient width - even `uintmax_t`.  Such a situation could occur on a platform where `(u)intptr_t` does not exist. IMO, when working with pointer to/from integer, using `uintptr_t` is better.  If  `uintptr_t` is absent, code's alternate approach is likely suspect too and best to not compile.

Comment: @chux Thanks for the criticism, but I think my answer already expresses your concerns. Do you have anything useful to add which hasn't already been covered?

Comment: Byte order doesn't matter for literals. It may be that on a little endian machine the value is stored as {0x50,0x8F,0x80,...}. Indeed here's a platform where that happens. http://ideone.com/7OU7GY. Though I have used `uintptr_t` for maximum guarantee that I'm using a pointer compatible type (if such a thing is available...).

Comment: `printf("%s", (void *) ptr_as_integer);`  Did you want `"%p\n"`?

Comment: @chux No. That pointer points at a string. I meant `%s`. Please be more observant.

Comment: I would add "You could (thought shouldn't) when you are writing an application which is run under OS control". For firmware you just _cannot_ avoid hard coded address

Comment: @Persixty The specs for `%p` state that the result is itself implementation-defined, meaning that the pointer may be printed little-endian, or it may be printed big-endian... or it may be completely non-functional, depending upon choices of the implementation... In this case we are to assume a functional implementation, but the integer literal is nonetheless always *interpreted* as *big-endian*, which is where my byte-order concerns come from. If you were to use `scanf("%p", &some)void_ptr)` to "deserialise" the pointer, OTOH, there would be no problem there.

Comment: `"%s"` expects a `char *`, not a `void *`.  Although common that `void *` and `char*` have similar attributes and width, they are not specified the same. `printf("%s", (char *) ptr_as_integer);` makes more sense.  The `...` of `printf()` provides no automatic conversion of `void *` to `char *`.

Comment: @chux No conversion is necessary. According to the standard, the two types are required to have the same representation *for this exact reason*!

Comment: No, they are not the same... For example, however irrelevant it is to this answer, you can't dereference a `void *`. Contrary to your belief, as [6.2.5p28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28) states, *"A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type<sup48</sup>"* with the footnote 48 reading *"The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions"*.

Comment: @Seb but this is debatable, because the `char*` - `void*` is listed in for `va_args` (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.1p2) but not mentioned in [7.1.4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4), and footnotes non-normative. Not that I'd believe anyone would do such a thing on purpose.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That section may be debatable on its own, but when paired with 6.2.5p28 and footnote 48 the debate comes to an end.

Comment: @Seb Thanks for that. Right you are. I've never encountered a platform where it came up. Because actually trying to use output as input is bizarre. But I have used them to look at things like alignment in debugging and the low-digits are always (in my experience) what you expect them to be!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `char *` to alias a pointer of another type to read individual bytes:

```
int i;
char *p = (char *)ptr;
for (i=0; i<sizeof(*ptr); i++) {
    printf("p[%d]=%02hhx", i, p[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int num = 10;
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &num;

    //To output the address of the "num" variable
    printf("Address: %p\n", ptr);

    //Address is 0x7fff47808f50...

    //Using that address to print the data at variable "num"
    printf("Data: %d\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
 }
```

the answer to you question is YES.

BUT:

1. You must be 100% sure what address to use. For example in any kind of firmware you always have addresses of registers defined in manuals as regular numbers. and we use them like this

   ```
   #define MY_REG_ADDR 0x12345ABC
   int a = *((int*)(MY_REG_ADDR))
   ```
2. Modern OSes do address randomization so executable's virtual address sapce is changed every time you run your application so you CANNOT just use hardcoded address.

here is the output after i ran the app 4 times (modified code)

Address: 0x7ffc279af5ac
Data: 10
Address: 0x7ffc2d78021c
Data: 10
Address: 0x7fffb36ae32c
Data: 10
Address: 0x7ffca2c2a9ec
Data: 10

3. Every tine you change your code memory layout might change so variabl's address might also change

Comment: Exactly, that's what I got few minutes ago. The address was continuously changing after every compilation.

Comment: @YatendraRathore not only after every compilation but with [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) in modern OSes the address will change after every run